# How can I parse a format where commas are not escaped (see example)

Tags: python

I have to parse a string like this

```
foo.bar (>=1.2.3, <2.0.0), baz, bazbaz (>1.2.3)
```

Where the number of items can be variable of course (currently three), and I want the result to be a list such as

```
[
  ("foo.bar", [">=1.2.3", "<2.0.0"]),
  ("baz", []),
  ("bazbaz", [">1.2.3"])
]
```

as you can see, it's not immediately trivial due to the presence of commas in two different contexts, and the variability of structure of the part in parenthesis, which may or may not be present. Splitting on the comma obviously doesn't work. Using regexp is also not trivial due to the changing nature of the groups.

I would like to create a miniparser to do it, but I have never created one so which module or library is it normally used to create something like this, and how would the input look like?

Comment: That's not a string

Comment: @NicolasGervais then what is it?

Comment: I think [`lark`](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark) can help you with that. It would take only a few lines to define your grammar to parse your language.

Comment: If the contents of the parenthesised parts don't themselves include parenthes, this looks easy to parse with a couple of regexes. But then again, your question might be misleading because it doesn't provide a full specification of all the possible elements.

Comment: @Asocia can you please show me how that would be done in lark. My objective is exactly to see a simple example of parsing done by someone that has done it.

Comment: Your question title is very misleading, because it doesn't mention that you specifically want to do it using a custom lexer. The last part of your question also sounds like you are asking people to recommend tools/libraries.

Comment: @ekhumoro I am not asking for recommendation. I would like to use a parser to parse it, but I don't know which one, and I would like to see an implementation that uses one, any one.

Comment: @StefanoBorini What's stopping you from doing the necessary research yourself? There are [plenty of resources available](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/) that outline all the options. Why not just give [lark](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark) a go and see where it takes you? It has [lots of well-documented examples](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/tree/master/examples) to help get you started, as well as [a complete tutorial for writing a json parser](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/master/docs/json_tutorial.md). Of course, I'm not actually recommending it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

s = "foo.bar (>=1.2.3, <2.0.0), baz, bazbaz (>1.2.3)"
result = []
for i in re.findall(r"([a-z.]+)\s*(\(.*?\))?", s):
    result.append(tuple(j.strip("()").split(",") if "," in j else j for j in i))
    
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[
    ('foo.bar', ['>=1.2.3', ' <2.0.0']), 
    ('baz', ''), 
    ('bazbaz', '(>1.2.3)')
]
```

Comment: Ok this is amazing and all, but I should have clarified that my question is about wanting to learn how to use a parser to do this.

Comment: @StefanoBorini Before you edited your question, you originally had stated, "If I have to create a miniparser, I'm fine with that." You are singing quite a different song now after people (myself included) have spent time and effort on this.

Comment: Output should be (in part): `('baz', [])`

Comment: @Booboo that's why I edited the question. it was misleading

Comment: @StefanoBorini I know you did. My only point is that someone might spend time and effort to no avail before you do clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

First the string is split on commas (followed by optional whitespace) that are not preceded by a digit. Then each resulting item is matched against:

```
(\S+)\s*(?:\(([^)]+)\))?
```

1. `\S+)` 1 or more non-whitespace characters
2. `\s*` - or more white space characters
3. `\(` Matches '('
4. `([^)]+)` Matches 1 or more non ')' characters captured in group 1
5. `\)` Matches ')'
6. `?` Items 3 through 5 are optional

The code:

```
import re

s = 'foo.bar (>=1.2.3, <2.0.0), baz, bazbaz (>1.2.3)'

items = re.split(r'(?<![0-9]),\s*', s)
results = []
for item in items:
    m = re.fullmatch(r'(\S+)\s*(?:\(([^)]+)\))?', item)
    if not m:
        raise Exception('Syntax Error')
    g2 = m.group(2)
    if g2:
        results.append((m.group(1), re.split(r',\s*', g2)))
    else:
        results.append((m.group(1), []))

print(results)
```

Prints:

```
[('foo.bar', ['>=1.2.3', '<2.0.0']), ('baz', []), ('bazbaz', ['>1.2.3'])]
```

**Update**

For tools for creating your own parsers, the following [website](https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/) is a good resource.